# How to convert a collection of numbers into other base

Tags: python

Again firstly I am sorry because keep asking the same question.I am new to python programming. I am now trying to build a program which convert every element in a list of numbers of base 10 into its base 4. For example here, say i have numbers from 0 to 20 or more, I want to convert every number starting from 0 to numbers of base 4. The result should be like this

```
[[0,0],[0,1],...[1,1,0]
```

for numbers starting from 0 to 20. For the code,here is what I wrote so far

```
for n in range(21):
   def base(n,b):
      result = []
      while n > 0:
             result.insert(0, n % b)
             n = n // b
      return result



print(base(n, 4))
```

For the result I got only for number 20 which is

```
[1,1,0]
```

Did I missed something here or there is another option to make it work?
Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're defining the function *inside* the loop. What you want to do is define the function first, then construct your desired list:

```
def base(n,b):
    result = []
    while n > 0:
        result.insert(0, n % b)
        n = n // b
    return result

print [base(n, 4) for n in range(21)]
```

(See [this article](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) if you're new to list comprehensions.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are defining the function inside the loop body, and only call it once. The structure you actually need is

```
<define the function>
for n in range(21):
    print(base(n, 4))
```

The results will print out, but each one on a separate line. To create a list of the results you should replace the two lines of the loop with a single line that prints a list of all results, like

```
print([base(n, 4) for n in range(21)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the numbers, then indent your print statement, so that it's part of the loop.

If you want these as strings, then convert the digits to characters and concatenate them.

I've done both here:

```
def base(n, b):
    result = []
    while n > 0:
        result.insert(0, n % b)
        n = n / b
    return result

for decimal in range(21):
    print(''.join(str(digit) for digit in base(decimal, 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually compute the base of a number by doing something like this:

```
from math import log
from math import floor

def n_to_base(n, b):
        num = n
        lead_idx = floor(log(num, b))
        b_rep = int(10**lead_idx)
        b_rep = str(b_rep)
        rep = 0
        for i in range(len(b_rep)-1, -1, -1):
            coeff = floor(num/(b**i))
            rep += int(coeff*(10**i))
            num -= int(coeff*(b**i))
        return rep
```